# AWS PHP SDK - Polly Neural voices (NTTS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-php-sdk, amazon-polly

What needs to be set to have the voice return as a neural voice instead of standard?

I'm trying to use neural voices using the PHP SDK 2016-06-10. I understand it is supported primarily just for en-US and en-UK - but for some reason, even after specifying **both region (en-US) and Engine (neural)**, the returned audio is just the standard one (Joanna).

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you're using an AWS region where NTTS is available? US East (N. Virginia), US West (Oregon), Europe (Ireland) and Asia-Pacific (Sydney).

BTW, 'en-US' is the language, not the region. API doc at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-polly-2016-06-10.html#synthesizespeech

If you're sure about the region, please share your code.